# Ensuring Client / Server Authentication without credentials

Tags: security, ssl, https, certificate

I am looking into ways of securing the channel between my client apps and the server.

I have a rich desktop client (win) and mobile client connecting to a webservice, exchanging data.

Using SSL certificates, server and clients may trust each other. On the secured connection i can exchange username and password and therefore authenticate the user.

However i have certain circumstances where a user must connect to the server via any of the two methods without his credentials but only a literal, like say, a license plate number.

I really want to make sure that in this case i ONLY allow client connects from devices i am sure i know, since there is no further checks on the authentication and a license plate number would be a pretty common literal.

How can i ensure that only "devices" which are known to my server, can interact with my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to authenticate the device, you'll need to find a way for the device to prove what it is, without disclosing its secret.

A system similar to a number plate would be quite easy to spoof, for anyone in a position to see that number. Depending on how much control you have on this device, you might not be able to hide it, even if the connection to your server is secured with SSL/TLS.

A potential way to do this would be to use a cryptographic hardware token (or smart card). Some of these tokens can be configured to hold a certificate and private key, with the ability to use the private key without being able to export that private key. The cryptographic operations (signing and decryption) happen on the token itself.

You can use these to perform client-certificate authentication to your server. In this case, you would know that the client has that token. This could work on the condition that you know the CAs were issued its certificates only for key pairs in such tokens: there will be a cost in administering the CA to handle this.

This would at least allow you to tie the authentication to a particular token. Whether you can integrate this with your overall device depends on the kind of device you have.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if TLS Pre-Shared Keys ([RFC 4279](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4279)) can be used for your scenario.

Comment: How does this help tying the pre-shared key to a particular device and no other copy?